# Join tables and sort by max date between the two tables and it's entries (there are two dates each)

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables `sgroup` and `sitem`. both **sgroup** and **sitem** have a `created` and `modified` property (which are of type DATETIME and can be NULL).
There can be many **sitem** entries for each **sgroup**. I'd like to create a query that will return to me the properties of the group as well as the **MAX** of all of the sitem(s) or sgroup datetimes. 
It's always possible modified is null (though this can be changed). It's possible there are 0 **sitem**s. +1 if I can sort the results by date.
Here's an example.
**sgroup**: || id || a || b || c || created || modified ||
|| 1 || xyz || def || qwe || 2024-01-03 00:31:55 || NULL ||
|| 2 || wer || ert || rty || 2024-01-04 00:12:12 || 2024-01-07 00:32:51 ||
**sitem**: || id || gid || d || e || created || modified ||
|| 1 || 1 || hio || kso || 2024-01-06 00:31:55 || NULL ||
|| 1 || 2 || kop || noa || 2024-01-07 00:12:55 || NULL||
`gid` is a foreign key from **sitem** to **sgroup**. `id` is the primary key for both tables. As you notice Group 1 has 2 items, and Group 2 has no items.
I'd like to perform a query and return something like the following:
|| id || a || b || c || latest ||
|| 2 || wer || ert || rty || 2024-01-07 00:32:51 ||
|| 1 || xyz || def || qwe || 2024-01-07 00:12:55 ||
As you can see the second group's latest datetime which is its modified property. In the first group the latest date comes from the creation of sitem 2. I'd like to receive only these 2 entries describing the groups.

Comment: Remove the irrelevant columns, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the watered down test case, and display the incoming data and desired results in tabular form.